# namespace gsap / Vite Template

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, es6-modules, gsap

I am working on a Vite / JavaScript / Webflow template so it's easier to use JavaScript inside Webflow, and of course GSAP.

I have GSAP as a dependency (thank you GS ), but when trying to call gsap this namespace gsap is the first one that pops up, so when hitting 'tab' to expand & auto-import, nothing happens. Now you'd say this is not a real problem, and you would be right, but I love better developer experience, and I want to make it easier for non-import-modules guys to get started easily.
[autocomplete doesn't correctly provide the GSAP library for better DX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj0PL.png)

My **jsconfig.json**  looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "ESNext" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "removeComments": true /* Strict Type-Checking Options */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,

    /* Additional Checks */
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */ /* Do not emit comments to output. */
  }
}
```

There are a couple of options which I don't totally understand (also I don't actually understand what namespace is) -
I saw it in a similar TypeScript/esbuild template (taken from tsconfig.json), where calling gsap popped the gsap library & auto-autoimport in the first position of the expanded menu (pic 2)

[*autocomplete correctly showing gsap library as 1st option in a .ts environment of another starter template*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wEqL.png)

My **vite.config.js** looks like this, in case it's needed:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";
import InjectHMRPlugin from "./config/vite-plugin-inject-hmr.js";
import RedirectRootRequestsPlugin from "./config/vite-plugin-redirect-root-requests.js";

export default defineConfig(({ command }) => {
  let config = {
    // Shared configuration across all modes
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        // Make root ("/") point to "src" folder
        "/": "src",
      },
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
      exclude: ["jquery"],
    },
    server: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3000,
    },
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        // Direct string paths without path.resolve
        input: {
          main: "./src/main.js",
          about: "./src/about.js",
        },
        external: ["jquery"],
      },
    },
    // ...other shared configurations...
  };

  // Extend config for development environment
  if (command === "serve") {
    config = {
      ...config, // keep the shared config
      plugins: [InjectHMRPlugin(), RedirectRootRequestsPlugin(), eslint()],
      server: {
        ...config.server, // keep the shared server config
        hmr: {
          port: 3000, // Can be omitted if it's the same as server port
        },
      },
    };
  }

  return config;
});
```

Thank you everybody!

I tried to basically remove various jsconfig options in case it worked, but nothing really happened.